# JQueryUI resizestop event not bubbling with helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using Backbone View events to listen for JQueryUI's `resizestop`. This [worked with JQuery 1.6.4](http://jsfiddle.net/forresto/ndftV/), but [not with 1.7.1](http://jsfiddle.net/forresto/jauRx/). It seems to only be an issue with the resize `helper` on.

This is a super-specific bug, so the question is how does one debug such things?

**edit** Simplified test, without Backbone: http://jsfiddle.net/forresto/yXvmv/

Comment: Does the console show any javascript errors?

Comment: No, the event just isn't getting fired. It is only an issue for jquery 1.7 resizable with helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird that it's only happening with jQuery 1.7.1 and Backbone combined.

I don't know what the root cause is, but I was able to figure out a workaround by updating your call to resizable in the initialize method

```
this.$(".withhelper")
    .resizable({
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
          stop: this.resizestop
      });
```

Here's the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/paulyoder/jauRx/8/